# Split content of a column and get the other replicated

Tags: awk, split

I have a file (too large) with a structure like this

```
A B C,D,E,F
```

The third column contains 4 values (but could be variable) separated with commas. I would like to convert that file into

```
A B C
A B D
A B E
A B F
```

Basically replicating the first two and splitting the second into rows.

Any idea on how to do that in `awk`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$ awk '{n=split($3,a,/,/);for(i=1;i<=n;i++)print $1,$2,a[i]}' file
A B C
A B D
A B E
A B F
```